# Deploy SonarQube (via helm chart) in AKS using a microsoft sql server database with jDBC connection, is not working

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, sonarqube

We are deploying a sonarQube installation (version 9.7.1) into a Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), version 1.26.6 Via Helm chart.

This the oficial chart repository used: [Chart repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/tree/master/charts/sonarqube)

Get it from the official sonar documentation: [deploy-sonarqube-on-kubernetes](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/setup-and-upgrade/deploy-on-kubernetes/deploy-sonarqube-on-kubernetes/)

We have configured everything without any problems using postgresql passing all the database paramters in the helm commandline parameters using a JDBC connection, with this command:

```
helm upgrade --install sonarqube sonarqube/sonarqube --version 6.0.1+425 --set image.tag=9.7.1-developer --set jdbcOverwrite.enable=true 
         --set jdbcOverwrite.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://mypostgresdb.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres 
         --set jdbcOverwrite.jdbcUsername=sonar@mypostgresdb --set  jdbcOverwrite.jdbcPassword=xxxxxxxxx 
         --set postgresql.enabled=false
```

But now we wanted to change the database to Sql Server and we have used the same commands but changing the JDBC connetion parameters:

```
helm upgrade --install sonarqube sonarqube/sonarqube --version 6.0.1+425 --set image.tag=9.7.1-developer --set jdbcOverwrite.enable=true 
             --set jdbcOverwrite.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=mymssqlsonardb   
             --set jdbcOverwrite.jdbcUsername=sonar --set  jdbcOverwrite.jdbcPassword=xxxxxxxxx 
             --set postgresql.enabled=false
```

In this case we got that error:

```
023.12.04 13:00:42 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting Web Server

2023.12.04 13:00:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 9.7.1.62043 / 13c69ab992096c497badccbdb4a31110594574fd

2023.12.04 13:00:47 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:sqlserver://mssqlserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=mymssqlsonardb

2023.12.04 13:00:48 INFO  web[][c.z.h.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2023.12.04 13:00:56 ERROR web[][c.z.h.p.HikariPool] HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open server "mssqlserver" requested by the login.  The login failed. ClientConnectionId:cf08e86b-5f9f-4722-803f-de8022daface

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:300)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:133)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6295)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4907)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4845)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7627)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3912)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3358)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2950)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2790)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1663)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)

    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.createHikariDataSource(DefaultDatabase.java:145)

    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.initDataSource(DefaultDatabase.java:134)

    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:112)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(StartableBeanPostProcessor.java:33)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:80)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel1.start(PlatformLevel1.java:164)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.start(PlatformImpl.java:196)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.startLevel1Container(PlatformImpl.java:162)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.init(PlatformImpl.java:76)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:72)

    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:55)

    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)

    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)

    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:104)

2023.12.04 13:00:56 WARN  web[][o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6a6824be-org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6a6824be-org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:80)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel1.start(PlatformLevel1.java:164)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.start(PlatformImpl.java:196)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.startLevel1Container(PlatformImpl.java:162)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.init(PlatformImpl.java:76)

    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:72)

    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:55)

    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)

    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)

    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:104)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database

    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:116)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(StartableBeanPostProcessor.java:33)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)

    ... 44 common frames omitted

Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Cannot open server "mssqlserver" requested by the login.  The login failed. ClientConnectionId:cf08e86b-5f9f-4722-803f-de8022daface

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)

    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.createHikariDataSource(DefaultDatabase.java:145)

    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.initDataSource(DefaultDatabase.java:134)

    at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:112)

    ... 48 common frames omitted

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open server "mssqlserver" requested by the login.  The login failed. ClientConnectionId:cf08e86b-5f9f-4722-803f-de8022daface

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:300)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:133)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6295)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4907)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4845)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7627)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3912)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3358)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2950)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2790)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1663)

    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1064)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)

    ... 53 common frames omitted

2023.12.04 13:00:56 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000

2023.12.04 13:00:56 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process

2023.12.04 13:00:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped

2023.12.04 13:00:57 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 143

2023.12.04 13:00:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped

2023.12.04 13:00:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

It seems something related with the server not with te database, but i think that the problem is that the Helm chart for Sonar is not ready for this kind of connections, because both JDBC connnections URL has been validated with a dbveaver database client and it was succesfull.

Any ideas, because we have tried any combination of helm chart available paramters and it can´t connect.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server error logs on the targeted instance? If you're seeing any error 18456 events (login failures) from Sonar then it is actually able to connect, then you can compare the `State` numbers in the events against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the issue that you need to correct.

Comment: In azure there are no error logs, i have queried master database with SELECT *
FROM sys.event_log
WHERE event_type = 'connection_failed'
But nothing about error codes only that:

event_catgory: conectivity
event_type: connection_failed
event_subtype_desc: login_Failed_for_user
description: Login failed for user.